# How to find Drawn Polygon intersection with layer elements in OpenLayers

Tags: openlayers-2, geoserver

I draw polygon vectors and I can find intersection to each other:

```
vactorTest.features[0].geometry.intersects(vactorTest.features[1].geometry)
```

but I want to find which layer elements this polygon intersects.

How can I find it?

EDIT:

I have vector layer like this:

```
layerArray = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS(wms_layer_configs[i].label, "http://somelink/geoserver/wms",
        {
        // srs: 'EPSG:xxxx',
            layers: workspace + ":" + wms_layer_configs[i].name,
            tilesOrigin: map.maxExtent.left + ',' + map.maxExtent.bottom,
            format: 'image/png',
            transparent: true
        }, {
            opacity: 0.75,
            isBaseLayer: false,
            visibility: false
        });
```

than I draw polygon and want to display on the map features from layer which intersects this drawn polygon

Comment: Hi @Iliaka, can you share the code that you used for fetching the layer elements that intersects with the Vector Polygon?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you meant saying "layer elements"? If layer elements is features you can use the following approach:

```
result = []
testPolygon = vectorTest.features[0].geometry;
for (var i=1; i<vectorTest.features.length; i+=1) {
    if testPolygon.intersects(vectorTest.features[i].geometry) {
        result.push(vectorTest.features[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: NO, intersection to each other is not problem for me. I have another layers where I have geom objects and I want to find intersection between this geom objects to the drawn polygon

Comment: I edited my question

Comment: Use needed layer inside for loop: for (var i=1; i<LAYERNAME.features.length; i+=1)

Comment: I tried but did not work, I'll try again now

Comment: WMS is not vector layer and you cannot check intersection on client side.

Comment: Yes you are right, it's WMS and it does not have layer.features property. so what do u advise me? to write function in DB side and there to check intersections?

Comment: As I can see you use GeoServer. GeoServer supports most the spatial filters: http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/tutorials/cql/cql_tutorial.html

Comment: Thank you very much, with this filter BBOX(the_geom, -90, 40, -60, 45) I can get result from GeoServer